# Two Formik Forms in a single Component messing "touched"

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have created two Formik Forms in a single component. In my 2nd Form, I am getting touched values of form 1 instead of Form 2.

```
activeForm === A ? (
<Formik
    initialValues={Form_B_values}
    validationSchema={Form_B_ValidationSchema}
    onSubmit={submit}
>
    {(formik) => (
    <>
        {/* This is displaying touched for Form A instead of Form B */}
        {console.log(formik.touched)}
        ...
    </>
    )}
</Formik>
) : (
<Formik
    initialValues={Form_A_values}
    validationSchema={Form_A_ValidationSchema}
    onSubmit={setActiveFormToB}
>
    ...
</Formik>
);
```